# Target different iphone versions with ionic

Tags: css, iphone, ionic-framework

I wonder if there is a proper way to do this with css. I am building an ios app using ionic and I'm in charge of the css mainly. I find that the design changes a lot when testing with an iphone 4/4s and then with a 6+. I can't make one design that fits both versions of the phone so I need to make a few tweaks to the css depending on the device it's going to run it. How would be the best way to approach this?

Right now the app looks mostly fine for an iphone 5, but the 6+ has too much space in some places and the 4/4s looks too busy, sometimes needing scroll/buttons overlapping due to its size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use media queries like this:

```
/* for iPhone 6+ */ 
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

There is a cool [collection of all media queries for Apple devices](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPhone) by Stephen Gilbert.